# Android app development environment and tools used

Tags: android, ide

I want to develop android apps. What all is required to set an environment for it in my personal pc? What is the required system specification. Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Please ask Google first and come back if you need further help in development issues. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need
Windows 7/Linux os/Window xp
Ram:2GB or higher (ddr3)
Android SDK kit
if you dont have internet connection please download offline android sdk.
I will give you the link later
for better performance keep the system up to date.Need a better graphics support

Answer (score 1):

Use this link http://developer.android.com/tools/index.html

Or Simply follow these step

1. if you are using Window Sun java from oracle  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
2. Android Sdk From http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html for Windows version
3. Eclipse plugin for http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Download all these thing mentioned above

Install `java` into system
set java path into system Environmentals variable from bin folder into the current `jdk`
set Path of Platform tools and tools

start eclipse plugin and create desktop shortcut

select workspace

select `help ->install new Software -> install ADT plugin` for android download and install http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

Select `windows-> preference ->Android -> select android sdk folder` click apply
update the sdk into the `windows-> preference ->Sdk Manager`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to develop for android is to download the [Eclipse IDE](http://www.eclipse.org/) as well as the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)
How to install it you can read on the official [Android Developers Page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)